# Cocos2D equivalent code for this?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my app before, I was using box2D methods to move my bodies around but now I changed it so that I am controlling my CCSprites directly. Anyway I have this code:

```
myBody->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(AccelPoint.x, -40.0f), myBody->GetPosition());
```

myBody was a b2Body. And AccelPoint.x was the x value so my body could moves around controlled by the UIAccelerometer only on the X axis.

Also, the -40 was a constant for gravity.

So, what would be the equivalent in Cocos2D code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store a velocity for the sprite, and every time step add a little bit to that velocity in the direction of the force. Then just move the sprite by the velocity each time step.

Comment: I see. What kind of velocity are you talking about (like what kind of object)? And when you say time step, you mean the game loop right? Also this would be a negative value right?

Comment: Velocity is just the direction and speed the thing is currently moving, usually two floats, like a b2Vec2. Yeah, time step is just one iteration of the game loop. Since it's a direction it's not really either negative or positive.

Comment: Just use a CGPoint to store the velocity. Then do: sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x + velocity.x, sprite.position.y + velocity.y); every frame

Comment: Ok I see. But what I am confused about is what do you mean by add little by little in the time step. What do you mean, do you have any examples?